# Does calling https service by Resttemplate work for all services whose certificate has been imported in the trustore of my client service?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate

I have a restemplate which can make call to multiple external systems over https.

I configured the resttemplate like so :

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(key, keyPassword)
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                client);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);

        return new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
```

I have setup 2 mock services on 2 separate VMs with ssl enabled and I am testing this restemplate by calling those services over https. And it works.

What I want to confirm is that configuring the restemplate as shown in the above code and importing the certificates of the different services to be called in by the client truststore should work without any additional configurations right? 
I am confused because in the code in this example here : https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-rest-clientcertificates-docker-compose the author has used 2 different factories i.e. serverTomClientHttpRequestFactory & serverAliceClientHttpRequestFactory, however mine works with a single restemplate. can someone please shed some light on this topic?

Comment: Do you have 2-way-ssl enabled on the serverside?

Comment: No it's one way ssl. The client service calls ssl enabled services.

Comment: if I read the headlines on the github link correctly, that's exactly the point. If you have 2-way-ssl, you MUST have a client certificate, if 1-way, you don't need it, and that's why your code is working.  Although it doesn't make sense to me in a 2-way-ssl scenario to have multiple different client certificates. but well.